# How to generalize this MATLAB code for Householder QR factorization

Tags: algorithm, matlab, matrix-factorization

I am asking for help to generalize the code I did for the first step in the Householder QR factorization. I have done the following:

```
A=[60,41,-88;42,60,51;0,-28,56;126,82,-71];
disp(A)
m=length(A(:,1));
n=length(A(1,:));
I=eye(m);
e1=I(:,1)';

    %We compute the first step of the method.
    beta=-sqrt(A(:,1)'*A(:,1));
    y=A(:,1)'-beta.*e1;
    alpha=sqrt(2)/(sqrt(y*y'));
    v=alpha*y;
    U=I-(v'*v);
    disp(U)
    R1=U*A;
    disp(R1)
```

and I have tried the following to do the rest of the steps:

```
for k=2:n
  ek=I(:,k)';
 for j=0:k
  beta=-sqrt(R1(k+j,k)'*R1(k+j,k));
   end
   disp(beta)
end

%For the standard basis just define A=eye(N), so the vectors are
%A(:,i).
```

But it didn't work, it gives an error that says the following:

> Attempted to access R1(5,3); index out of bounds because
>   size(R1)=[4,3].
>
> Error in Householderfactorization (line 33)
>       beta=-sqrt(R1(k+j,k)'*R1(k+j,k));

So I have been trying to search for another way to get the algorithm, but I can't figure out how to do this, I have read the book "Numerical analysis" by Kincaid & Cheney 1st edition to get a clarification, but after reading I've got more confused (I want to perform the algorithm in the book since it is the easiest I have found,in spite is a little bit confusing).

Can someone help me to perform this algorithm in the right way please?

> Note: The book can be found [Here](http://gen.lib.rus.ec/book/index.php?md5=C6FD7E3C3868A7BA62AC7E1DF9B788A2), in fact is in page 253. So the thing is that I want to translate the algorithm of the parts after the first one into a MATLAB code (that is generalization I am talking about), and the problem this algorithm has is that when you want to compute the second step and forward you have to consider the previous matrices and then you have to change, for example, your A(:,1) to [R1(2,2),R1(3,2),R1(4,2)]' and then compute all you did in the first step using this new vector, so this process is the one I don't know how to translate this to MATLAB. The first step is easy, the other ones are difficult for me.

Comment: Well, You should probably do some research on what is Your `beta` parameter and how is it defined, because You are trying to construct it from R1's elements that do not exist...

Comment: Well, I have constructed a matrix called R1 from the elements of A, so the next step is to construct matrices Rk from the previous R's but that is the thing I don't know how to performed since the algorithm says that it is like a stair, right, so I have clear what is the beta parameter, but I don't know how to say to the computer  "ok, once you have R1 construct the other beta and so on " :)

Comment: Then You must have some simple mistake in Your second for loop, where You call R1(j+k,k) because for j = k = n You are getting R1(2n,n) which is clearly out of bounds, as matlab is telling You.

Comment: So then, How can I fix my code to have all the steps? Thanks :)

Comment: I'm sorry but You will need to do more research on what is Your algorithm supposed to do, understand it, work it out on paper and then translate it to matlab code again.. good luck

Comment: Right, I have already understand what does the algorithm has to do, the thing is the translation part, I need you help in generalizing that part :)